# Power Shell Script cant find C disk

Tags: powershell, disk

So I've been trying to make a script that copies all the files from a users "Documents", "Photos"-folders and so on to a single folder on another drive. 
But the script keeps saying:

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '‪c' does not exist.
At C:\Users\sebbe\Downloads\Untitled1.ps1:23 char:1
+ Copy-Item -Path "‪c:\Users\$user\Desktop\*" -Destination D:\mapp1\$us ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (‪c:String) [Copy-Item], DriveNotFoundExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I am running the script via Power Shell ISE as administrator, and I have tried the script on two different PCs, with the same failure.

Why can't the script find the C: disk?

Here is the whole script:

```
$User = Read-Host "New Username"

Function makeDir {
    New-Item -Path D:\mapp1 -Name "$User" -ItemType Directory 
}
Function copyDesktop {
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\$User\Desktop" -Destination "D:\mapp1\$User\Desktop" -Recurse
}

Function copyDocuments {
    Copy-Item -Path "‪C:\Users\$User\Documents" -Destination "D:\mapp1\$User\Documents" -Recurse
}

Function copyPictures {
    Copy-Item -Path ‪‪"C:\Users\$User\Pictures" -Destination "D:\mapp1\$User\Pictures" -Recurse
}

makeDir
copyDocuments
copyPictures
copyDesktop
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the paths in quotes? `Copy-Item -Path ‪‪'C:\users\$user\Pictures\*' -Destination 'D:\mapp1\$user\Pictures\'`

Comment: Yes, I have tried both with the ' and the "

Comment: What does `Get-PSDrive` say? Do you see a drive for letter C?

Comment: Yes, I do see a drive for the letter C. Thank you for your input! :)

Comment: @Seb Well your script makes sense so I had to make sure it wasn't something dumb :( Try `Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\$User\Desktop" -Destination "D:\mapp1\$User\Desktop" -Recurse`

Comment: @ShawnEsterman What you suggested works, somehow. Thanks!
But I still have the same problem while trying to copy the Documents and Pictures folders, and I cannot see what you did that made it work. 
Would you mind explain what you did, I am quite confused, haha. :) 
Thank you, once again! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it work, somehow.

This is how the code looks like now:

```
$User = Read-Host "New Username"

Function makeDir {
    New-Item -Path D:\mapp1 -Name "$User" -ItemType Directory 
}
Function copyDesktop {
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\$User\Desktop" -Destination "D:\mapp1\$User\Desktop" -Recurse
}

Function copyDocuments {
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\$User\Documents" -Destination "D:\mapp1\$User\Documents" -Recurse
}

Function copyPictures {
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\$User\Pictures" -Destination "D:\mapp1\$User\Pictures" -Recurse
}

makeDir
copyDocuments
copyPictures
copyDesktop
```

A big thanks to Shawn Esterman, and everyone else of course! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is most likely with PowerShell not being able to expand the strings properly. To ensure you have a string encapsulate your paths in quotes like  `"C:\users\$User\Documents"`. Then you don't want to use the `\*` at the end of your path. Just use `Copy-Item`'s built-in `-Recurse` parameter. If you don't use the recurse parameter you might need to run the copy multiple times.

```
$user = Read-Host "New Username"

Function makeDir {
    New-Item -Path D:\mapp1 -Name "$user" -ItemType Directory 
}

Function makeDesktop {
    New-Item -Path D:\mapp1\$user\ -Name "$user Skrivbord" -ItemType Directory 
}

Function makeDocuments {
    New-Item -Path D:\mapp1\$user\ -Name "$user Dokument" -ItemType Directory 
}

Function makePictures {
    New-Item -Path D:\mapp1\$user\ -Name "$user Bilder" -ItemType Directory 
} 

Function kopieraDesktop {
    Copy-Item -Path "‪C:\Users\$user\Desktop" -Destination "D:\mapp1\$user\Desktop"
}

Function kopieraDocuments {
    Copy-Item -Path ‪"C:\Users\$user\Documents" -Destination "D:\mapp1\$user\Documents"
}

Function kopieraPictures {
    Copy-Item -Path ‪‪"C:\users\$user\Pictures" -Destination "D:\mapp1\$user\Pictures"
}

makeDir
makeDesktop
makeDocuments
makePictures
kopieraDesktop
kopieraDocuments
kopieraPictures
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, and posted the new code in the main post. 
But I still recive the errors while trying to do the copy for the pictures and documents folders.

Comment: Does this happen for all users, or just some?  What do you get if you output "C:\users\$user\Pictures\" and "D:\mapp1\$user\Pictures" to the console?  Are the resulting strings valid paths?  That is, can you navigate to them, does the user running the script have access to them, etc?

Comment: Since I am running the script on two different PCs, yes, it hapends for all users. 

I do have access to the paths from Power Shell. :)

I find it strange, since the desktop-copy works, while the documents/pictures do not. They look the same to me (?)